# Wordpress: Custom post type with no single page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using wordpress as cms for a small website and i do not have a great deal of experience with wordpress. I am trying to create a custom post type with no single.php layout.

On the homepage of design of the website, there is a ticker that displays ... "Latest news" - I am able to create a custom post type, loop through it and display all news on the homepage. However this is leading to unintentional creation of links of each individual news item. Which i don't need.

How do i get rid of it? - is there a way to have custom post type with no "permalink" URL?

i searched google for the issue and seems like only way is to just use forced url redirection. But i wanted to know if there is a better way to achieve my goal?

is there anything else other than custom post types that can be used?

Answer (score 3):

If you are infact talking about linkable titles from your loop output then @JP Lew is correct. Remove the  tag from the loop.

In addition:
The post type will show up on your sitemap and they will be crawled by search engines. You must use a robots.txt file and include:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/
Disallow: /custom_type/
```

to tell bots to forget about directories that do not contain content like these custom post types and wp-content areas like the plugins directory. Also within your `register_post_type()` function's arguments the 'public' argument should be **set to false** for several related reasons including exclusion from WordPress search results,  wp-admin etc.

Comment: Thanks, Yoast has several great articles and robots.txt templates - http://bit.ly/AuiCG6

Answer (score -1):

in your homepage template you will find something like this:

```
<h2>Latest News</h2>
<ul>
<?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <?php

    endwhile;
?>
</ul>
```

Just get rid of the anchor tag linking to the `the_permalink` and you should be good to go. No need to "disable" the URL, just don't display it in your theme.